# How to sort object using a multi map?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, guava, multimap

Hi I'm trying to sort an object based on a value of that object. Originally I used TreeMap which did the sorting but there were some non-unique keys which were removed so that didn't work. I googled around and came across Guava MultiMap. But how do I actually use this to sort the values?

Basically I'm trying to sort budget information based on the diffYTD_percentage value. Thanks!

```
Multimap<Double, BudgetInformation> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    for (Budget budget : budgets) {
        BudgetInformation budgetInfo = getBudget(budget.getId());
        double actualToDate = budgetInfo.getActualToDate();
        double budgetToDate = budgetInfo.getTotalBudgetToDate();
        double diffYTD_value = budgetToDate - actualToDate;
        double diffYTD_percentage_value = 0.0;
        if (budgetToDate != 0.0) {
            double fraction = actualToDate / budgetToDate;
            fraction = fraction - 1;
            diffYTD_percentage_value = fraction * 100;
        }
        multiMap.put(diffYTD_percentage_value, budgetInfo);
    }

    Iterator<BudgetInformation> budgetIterator = multiMap.values().iterator();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Tree in order to sort collection is wrong approach. In Java there are dedicated utility methods to sort list, `Collections.sort(List<T extends Comparable<? super T>> list)` and `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`. The first is used to sort list where elements have natural ordering (basically implement `Comparable` interface), the later is used in cases like your own, when you need to sort elements using custom ordering.

So, basically what you need to do is to create `Comparator` that will compare two `BusinessInfo` instances based on `diffYTD_percentage_value` and call `Collections.sort` with this comparator.

```
    Comparator<BudgetInformation> budgetInfoCmp = new Comparator<BudgetInformation>() {
        private double getDiffYTDPercentage(BudgetInformation budgetInfo) {
            double actualToDate = budgetInfo.getActualToDate();
            double budgetToDate = budgetInfo.getTotalBudgetToDate();
            double diffYTDValue = budgetToDate - actualToDate;
            double diffYTDPercentageValue = 0.0;
            if (budgetToDate != 0.0) {
                double fraction = actualToDate / budgetToDate;
                fraction = fraction - 1;
                diffYTDPercentageValue = fraction * 100;
            }
            return diffYTDPercentageValue;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(BudgetInformation o1, BudgetInformation o2) {
            return Double.compare(getDiffYTDPercentage(o1), getDiffYTDPercentage(o2));
        }
    };

    List<BudgetInformation> budgetInformationsToSort = getBudgetInformations();
    Collections.sort(budgetInformationsToSort, budgetInfoCmp);
```

Also try to avoid using underscore in variable naming, as [under Java naming convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) variable names should be in camel case.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [TreeMultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html)? It doesnt support duplicate key-value pair. But duplicate keys are fine.

Comment: It won't let me put Class BudgetInformation into a TreeMultiMap. TreeMultiMap<double, BudgetInformation> does not work.

Comment: If you open that link you will find it says `Class TreeMultimap<K,V>` The key and value are generics. It can be double,long etc.

Comment: SO how can I then use it to sort BudgetInformation?

Comment: use the same `put` statement that you are using in your code snippet. It will internally order it by keys.

Comment: But what do I put in the TreeMultimap<Double, (What goes here)> ?

Comment: the exact same code that you wrote in your code snippet `put(diffYTD_percentage_value, budgetInfo);`

Comment: I get incompatible types no instances of type variables <K, V> so that TreeMultimap<K, V> conforms to TreeMultiMap<Double, BudgetInformation>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61833/discussion-between-abhiroop-sarkar-and-fionn).